# A question for puppeeter about mouse action doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to try to get some information about the page, but I encountered an anti-crawler page. I can solve the problem by dragging the slider on the actual page, but the mouse simulation of puppeteer does not seem to solve this problem. So I am here to ask how to solve it.
Here is my code:
userAgent.js

```js
const userAgents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070731 Ubuntu/dapper-security Firefox/1.5.0.12',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Acoo Browser; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1036.7 Safari/535.20',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko Fedora/1.9.0.8-1.fc10 Kazehakase/0.5.6',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.71 Safari/537.1 LBBROWSER',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 6.0) ,Lynx/2.8.5rel.1 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/1.2.9',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; QQBrowser/7.0.3698.400)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; QQDownload 732; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:2.0b13pre) Gecko/20110307 Firefox/4.0b13pre',
    'Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8; U; fr) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070731 Ubuntu/dapper-security Firefox/1.5.0.12',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; LBBROWSER)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko Fedora/1.9.0.8-1.fc10 Kazehakase/0.5.6',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux; en-US) AppleWebKit/527+ (KHTML, like Gecko, Safari/419.3) Arora/0.6',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; QQBrowser/7.0.3698.400)',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en), Lynx/2.8.5rel.1 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/1.2.9',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
];

module.exports = {
    userAgents
};
```

htmlService.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {userAgents} = require('./userAgent')

let puppeteerBrowser = null;

async function getHtmlContent(url) {
    const userAgent = userAgents[parseInt(Math.random() * userAgents.length)];
    const headers = {
        'User-Agent': userAgent,
        Accept:
            'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Cookie:
            'zh_choose=s; zh_choose=s; _gscu_1575893663=56268672godhjb19; _gscbrs_1575893663=1; _pk_id.52.d4c1=ca0b23081b215ee0.1556268673.2.1584608708.1584608646.; _pk_ref.52.d738=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1584838630%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F%22%5D; _pk_ses.52.d738=*; _gscs_1575893663=t84838630uv0y6117|pv:3; _pk_id.52.d738=54fee0e32da49e39.1584266678.6.1584838693.1584838630.',
        Pragma: 'no-cache',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1,
    };
    if (!puppeteerBrowser) {
        puppeteerBrowser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            slowMo: 250,
            args: ['-no-sandbox', '--window-size=1920,1080'],
        }, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    }
    let page = await puppeteerBrowser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => false})
    });
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    const sliderElement = await page.$('#nc_1_n1z.nc_iconfont.btn_slide');
    const sliderHandle = await page.$('#nc_1__scale_text.scale_text');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        let reportMousePosition = function(action) {
            return function(e){
                let mouseX = e.offsetX;
                let mouseY = e.offsetY;
                console.log(action, mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        }
        document.onmousemove = reportMousePosition('move');
        document.onmousedown = reportMousePosition('down');
        document.onmouseup = reportMousePosition('up');
    })
    if (sliderElement && sliderHandle) {
        console.log('here');
        const slider = await sliderElement.boundingBox();
        const handle = await sliderHandle.boundingBox();
        console.log([handle.x + handle.width / 2, handle.y + handle.height / 2])
        await page.mouse.move(handle.x + handle.width / 2, handle.y + handle.height / 2)
        await page.waitFor(10);
        await page.mouse.down()
        await page.waitFor(10);
        for (let i = 0; i < slider.width; i += 10) {
            for (let j = 0; j < handle.height; j += 10) {
                await page.mouse.move(handle.x + i, handle.y + j)
            }
        }
        await page.waitFor(10);
        await page.mouse.up()
        console.log([handle.x + slider.width, handle.y + handle.height / 2])
    }
    await page.waitFor(300);
    const html = await page.content();
    return html;
}

module.exports = {
    getHtmlContent
};
```

Then code run:

```js
const content = getHtmlContent('https://detail.1688.com/offer/532170321794.html');
```

You will encounter it frequently when you visit.

Comment: So the problem is: the mouse move doesn't prevent that you are recognized as a crawler? In this case it is not related to puppeteer mouse actions, but automated browser detection.

Comment: Yes, I think they have taken some measures. Is there any difference in mouse movement between the two? @theDavidBarton

Comment: both communicates to the browser, I think there is no difference in this case. but I think the crawler detection happen on a different level, when you start to move the mouse it is already detected you. you should try a different approach to pretend yourself as a real user.